# Group by using an if condition in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to group my logs using a particular condition. I have a set of logs out of which I extract time. Now based on the condition for time I want to filter out those logs and store them in memory itself (not in a separate file) to perform further calculations. The condition for time is as follows: 
If difference between 1st value and the remaining values in timestamps is <=5 then group them together. This goes on till all the logs have been partitioned based on the condition. Here's my code :

```
 logLine=sc.textFile("path\to\file").cache()
 lines = logLine.flatMap(lambda x: x.split('\n'))
 logs = lines.collect() 
 for line in logs :
     a = re.search(rx1,line)
     time = a.group() #extracting time from logs
     newlst.append(float(time))
     if (newlst[0] - newlst[-1]) <= 5.0 # Time condition. I got stuck here
         ......
```

`logs` -> containing all my logs

`newlst` -> containing only timestamps in float

How do i use the groupBy or filter condition (or if there is any other technique) to group by the logs based on the time condition . I tried group by and filter but not working.

Input:

```
1472120400.107 HTTP GEO er.aujf.csdh.jkhydf.eyrgt
1472120399.999 HTTP GEO er.asdhff.cdn.qyirg.sdgsg
1472120397.633 HTTP GEO er.abff.kagsf.weyfh.ajfg
1472120397.261 HTTP GEO er.laffg.ayhrff.agyfr.yawr
1472120394.328 HTTP GEO er.qfryf.aqwruf.oiuqwr.agsf
1472120393.737 HTTP GEO er.aysf.aouf.ujaf.casf
.
.
.
```

Final output based on the condition (1 set of logs):

```
1472120400.107 HTTP GEO er.aujf.csdh.jkhydf.eyrgt
1472120399.999 HTTP GEO er.asdhff.cdn.qyirg.sdgsg
1472120397.633 HTTP GEO er.abff.kagsf.weyfh.ajfg
1472120397.261 HTTP GEO er.laffg.ayhrff.agyfr.yawr
```

Comment: Is this rdd or DataFrame?

Comment: I've added more code. It's an rdd.

Comment: You load your data into memory with `collect()`, after that you don't have a distributed dataset anymore, is that intended?

Comment: Oh ok. I thought that `logs` still remains an rdd after collect.